# Find out the general solution of $\tan x + \cot 2x = 2$.

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve for $x$ in

$$\tan x + \cot 2x = 2.$$

I tried to write in terms of $\sin x $ and   $\cos x$ but couldn't get the answer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your idea should work, but it is easier to use the double angle formula for $\cot(2x)$ or $\tan 2x$. The one I remember is for $\tan(2x)$, which is $\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\tan x+\cot2x=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\dfrac{\cos2x}{2\sin x\cos x}=\dfrac{2\sin^2x+\cos2x}{2\sin x\cos x}=\csc2x$$  as $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$

$$\implies\sin2x=\dfrac12$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: How $$\frac{2sin^2x+cos2x}{2sin xcos x}=\cos2x$$Didn't understood.

Comment: @user302630, $$\cos2x+2\sin^2x=1$$  and $$\dfrac1{2\sin x\cos x}=\dfrac1{\sin2x}=\csc2x$$

Answer (score 2):

If you let $t = \tan x$, you can (using the double angle formula that Andre mentioned in his comment) transform the equation into:

$$t + \frac{1-t^2}{2t} = 2$$

which can easily be further arranged into a quadratic. Can you proceed?

Comment: It is coming $$t^2-4t+1=0$$. How can i solve this.and get a general solution?

Comment: @user302630 You get $t = 2 \pm \sqrt 3$, which you can either immediately recognise as being the tangent of the principal angles of $\frac{\pi}{12}$ or $\frac{5\pi}{12}$, or prove it by calculating $\tan 2t$ using the double angle formula. Either way, it's not as elegant a solution as lab's, and it's just that you gave him best answer.

Answer (score -1):

$\tan x+\cot 2x=2\implies(\sin x/\cos x)+(\cos2x/\sin2x)=0$.

Taking LCM,
$(\sin2x\sin x+\cos2x\cos x)/\sin2x\cos x=2$

{Using identity: $\cos(a-b)=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b$}

$(\cos x/\sin 2x\cos x)=2\implies \sin2x=1/2=\sin(\pi/6) $

$2x=n\pi+(-1)^n (π/6)\implies x=nπ/2 +(-1)^n (π/12)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax to make your solution easy to read!